# Install a go script to run from shell

Tags: go

I have a go script named `SSL_CHECK.go`. Now to run it I need to run it as `go run SSL_CHECK.go <<optiional arguments>>`

I want to compile this script so that I can execute it as a shell command.

For instance like `./ssl_check <<optional arguments>>` from the shell.

Can I achieve that in Go.

Comment: This process is called compilation. Search for "how to compile a go program".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you SSL_CHECK.go is in the package main, all you need to do is `go install` (as in "[Compile and install packages and dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)").

That will generate a `SSH_CHECK` executable and put it in your `$GOPATH/bin` folder, which should be referenced in your `$PATH`.